# Помогите с удалением пакета в Python

Tags: python

хочу удалить пакет с ботами на телеграмм, что требуется ввести в строчке `"Proceed (y/n)?"` просто не понимаю что от меня хотят

```
Found existing installation: telebot 0.0.4
Uninstalling telebot-0.0.4:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\никита\pycharmprojects\pythonproject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot-0.0.4.dist-info\*
    c:\users\никита\pycharmprojects\pythonproject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\*
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    c:\users\никита\pycharmprojects\pythonproject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py
    c:\users\никита\pycharmprojects\pythonproject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\handler_backends.py
    c:\users\никита\pycharmprojects\pythonproject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py
    c:\users\никита\pycharmprojects\pythonproject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py
    c:\users\никита\pycharmprojects\pythonproject1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\version.py
Proceed (y/n)?
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос не связан с программированием, и решается англо-русским словарем, Google Translate или другим переводчиком.

Answer (score 5):

Вас предупреждают о том, что пакеты будут удалены. Смело жмите `y`.

Answer (score 5):

Всегда говорил, что Google переводчик у IT-шника в закладках должен стоять раньше, чем SO. Вбиваем и вуаля:

> Обнаружена существующая установка: telebot 0.0.4 Удаление telebot-0.0.4: Удалило бы: c: \ users \ никита \ pycharmprojects \ pythonproject1 \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ telebot-0.0.4.dist-info * c: \ users \ никита \ pycharmprojects \ pythonproject1 \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ telebot * Не удаляет (может быть добавлено вручную): c: \ users \ никита \ pycharmprojects \ pythonproject1 \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ telebot \ apihelper .py c: \ users \ никита \ pycharmprojects \ pythonproject1 \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ telebot \ handler_backends.py c: \ users \ никита \ pycharmprojects \ pythonproject1 \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ telebot \ types.py c: \ users \ никита \ pycharmprojects \ pythonproject1 \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ telebot \ util.py c: \ users \ никита \ pycharmprojects \ pythonproject1 \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ telebot \ version.py Продолжить ( д / н)?

становится ясно, что менеджер всего лишь спрашивает, уверены ли Вы в своём решении. `(y/n)?`, как видно из перевода, просит Вас принять решение `Yes` или `No` и сообщить установщику о своём решении, нажав, соответственно, <kbd>y</kbd> или <kbd>n</kbd>. Так что, как уже ответил [@AlexeyLeshchenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/397961/alexey-leshchenko), смело жмите <kbd>y</kbd> (если ничего не произойдёт, то ещё и <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

И учитесь пользоваться переводчиком, да и линуксовыми инструментами тоже, раз уж на то пошло.

Comment: Да английский надо учить, а не переводчик. ;)